# Updating list using AJAX in Codeigniter (within a form)

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

I have a form that adds clients to a database `clients/add_client`. The `add_client` method has a parameter of `$state` which is passed to another method `list_centers()`. When someone is talking to a potential client, they have all of our centers in a sidebar. There is a `<select>` above the list of centers in which lists the states where we have centers. When they change the select to another state, it should list all of the centers in that state. Now, I have this working by passing the parameter in the URL like this: `localhost/clients/add_clients/GA` lists all of the centers in Georgia. The problem is that I want to do this with AJAX and not have the page refresh. I cannot figure out how to pass this data via ajax. I know that I have to reconstruct the list each time but I am stuck. Here is what I have tried:

```
$('#center_select').change(function(){
        var data = $(this).val();
        var url = 'add_client/' + data;
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            dataType: 'html',
            data: data,
            url: url,
            success: function(data) {
                console.log(data);
            },
            error: function(data) {
                console.log(data);  
            } 
        });
        return false;
    });
```

Just in case you need the method:

```
public function add_client($state = false) {

        $this->load->model('centers_model');

        $data = array(
            'page_title' => 'Add Client',
            'client_status' => $this->clients_model->list_client_status(),
            'centers' => $this->centers_model->list_centers(null, $state),
            'center_states' => $this->centers_model->list_center_states(),
        );

        $this->load->view('header');
        $this->load->view('clients/add_client', $data);
        $this->load->view('footer');

    }
```

View:

```
<div class="col-sm-3">
            <aside id="centers_sidebar" class="well">
                <h2>List of Centers</h2>
                <select class="form-control" name="center_select" id="center_select">
                    <option value="all">All</option>
                    <?php
                        foreach ($center_states as $center_state) {
                            echo '<option value="' . $center_state->center_state . '">' . $center_state->name . '</option>';
                        }
                    ?>
                </select>
                <ul id="center_list">
                    <?php
                        foreach ($centers as $center) {
                            $output = '<li class="center">';
                            $output .= '<h5>' . $center->center_name . '</h5>';
                            $output .= '<p>' . $center->center_type . '</p>';
                            $output .= '<p>' . $center->center_city . ', ' . $center->center_state . '</p>';
                            $output .= '<p>' . $center->center_phone . '</p>';
                            $output .= '</li>';
                            $output .= '<hr>';

                            echo $output;
                        }
                    ?>
                </ul>   
            </aside>
        </div>
```

Comment: you can do the get request. as per your controller you are not procesing any post data

Comment: @siddhesh I believe that I am on that track, but I do not know how to get the data using `GET` from AJAX.

Comment: `add_client($state=false)` needs to return html to the `success:` function of your ajax call. So instead of loading views you must build the html and then, in `Success` insert (or replace) that html in the appropriate element. Basically you just echo the html and Success will receive it.

Show your view html and I can provide example code.

Comment: in your page create one div with some id say page and in success callback $("#page").html(); whatever coming from the server will be inside the div one more thing there is no need of data property in ajax object when you r working with get request url,type and success and error callback will be sufficient please refer jquery docs for more info

Comment: @DFriend Added the view. Thanks for your help!

Comment: sorry I have not look at your html markup you have to create div which wraps your ul element

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I failed to notice that you request a POST but setup for a GET. So here we supply the proper structure to ajax.data

select handler

```
  $('#center_select').change(function () {
    var st = $(this).val();
      var url = 'update_centers';
    $.ajax({
      type: 'POST',
      dataType: 'html',
      data: {state: st},
      url: url,
      success: function (data) {
        console.log(data);
        $("#center_list").html(data);
      },
      error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        //useful for trouble shooting & error handling
        console.log(textStatus, errorThrown);
      }
    });
    return false;
  });
```

AJAX responder method - builds html to send back to `ajax.success`
We need to pull the input from $_POST (using input->post)
I've put in a bunch of validity checks and a general purpose ajax error response function too. No extra charge.

```
function update_centers()
{
  $this->load->model('centers_model');
  $state = $this->input->post('state');
  if(!isset($state))
  {
    $this->ajax_bad_request_error("No state data received");
    return;
  }

  $centers = $this->centers_model->list_centers(null, $state);
  if(!isset($centers))
  {
    $this->ajax_bad_request_error("The database failed to find centers in $state");
    return;
  }

  $output = "";
  foreach($centers as $center)
  {
    $output .= "<li class='center'><h5>$center->center_name</h5>"
      ."<p>$center->center_type</p>"
      ."<p>$center->center_city, $center->center_state</p>"
      ."<p>$center->center_phone</p></li><hr>";
  }
  echo $output;
}

function ajax_bad_request_error($msg)
{
  //All purpose reporting of ajax failure
  header('HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request');
  header('Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8');
  $data = array('type' => 'error', 'message' => $msg);
  echo json_encode($data);
}
```

Cannot guarantee this will work perfectly as is - syntax errors may exist. But the concept is sound.

Comment: This is quite a bit off. I have tried to use that code many different ways and it is not working. I will keep working on it.

Comment: Off? How? Where/how does it fail?

Comment: I am thinking that the `data` passed to the `success` function is off. It only loads the current page html. Also, the `foreach` uses `$centers` which is not defined, so I changed it to `$data['centers']` but there are still problems. At best, it echos the results at the top of the page.

Comment: The only html my example returns is the information about a particular state's centers. In the function `add_client` `$centers` is defined by the return from the database. I've made the assumption that the database does in fact return something. So, if `$centers` is throwing an undefined error look at the model.

Comment: The model is working correctly because when I go to `localhost/clients/add_client/FL` the only centers that show are the ones from Florida. I am not understanding where the AJAX is supposed to be getting the data from. What is being returned to it?

Comment: I believe I see the problem. Give me few and I'll update my answer

Comment: It is still not working. I uploaded the site so that you could look at it. The AJAX is returning the whole page of HTML. http://admissions.teenchallenge.cc/clients/add_client

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/95382/discussion-between-dfriend-and-dc-tc).